# Most effecient cross browser way to convert this jquery to Pure JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

What in your opinion would be the best way to convert this jquery to pure js inclusive of IE. (attach event/ addeventlistener)

```
$('.star.rating').click(function(){
  console.log( $(this).parent().data('stars') + ", " + $(this).data('rating'));

  $(this).parent().attr('data-stars', $(this).data('rating'));
});
```

Comment: "Pure JS" => "Pure DOM" - the **language** isn't changed. I mention this because knowing you're looking for how to use the DOM makes it easier for you to find resources, such as...https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model

Comment: Where specifically are you stuck? Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the parent you could use `.parentNode` on the element that triggered the handler.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.star.rating').forEach(elem, function() {
    elem.addEventListener('click', setRating);
});

function setRating() {
    var rating = this.getAttribute('data-rating');
    var parent = this.parentNode;
    var stars = parent.getAttribute('data-stars');

    console.log(stars + ", " + rating);

    parent.setAttribute('data-stars', rating);
}
```